# How to use classes that are compiled with babel and exported with Webpack in the browser

Tags: gulp, ecmascript-6, webpack, babeljs

I have a project for a websocket-based library that has components that need to run in both Node and the browser. Currently the library is organized and built as follows:

- All the different components are written into their own es6 files.
- The components that are used in the browser are transpiled into es5 files (using babel)
- The transpiled files are then aggregated into one file (using webpack and the babel loader)

How do I access the various classes defined in the components in the browser? (i.e. how do I get the equivalent of `var Client = require("client");` to work?)

P.S. - I'm using Gulp to manage all of this, so answers that include gulp solutions are especially appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I hope, I got you right, but what you wanna do is basically to open your dev-tools in the browser and type `client.myFunction()`, right?

If so, you need to attach your library `client` to the global namespace or to the window object. This needs to happen in your main entry point file, where all your other submodules are imported.

Example (client.js)

```
import {myFunction} from './functions';
import {myConstant} from './constants';

const Client = {
    myFunction, // or: myFunction: myFunction (if you do not use ES7)
    myConstant
};

window.Client = Client; // or global.Client = Client;
```

Now you would include your script bundle in an HTML page via script-tag and should be able to call `window.Client.myFunction()`, i.e. `Client.myFunction()` in the browser or on your page.

Is that, what you were looking for? Let me know!

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but that's not exactly the problem I'm having. I'm trying to create some modules that work on both Node and the browser (so I can't reference the window object in my code since it's not defined in Node). I can get everything packaged up and transpiled with webpack but once I do there's no way to reference my classes (that I know of).

Comment: So you are looking for an isomorphic implementation of your module. In that case, you need to define different entry points for your module: one for node and one for your browser.

https://github.com/matthew-andrews/isomorphic-fetch/blob/master/package.json

You see the browser attribute and the main attribute in the package.json of isomorphic-fetch for example